# Read code markers of a images

Tags: vb.net, augmented-reality, emgucv

I do not know the real name of this type of "QR" they are used in augmented reality and other tracking applications.
Here is a image of what it looks like.

[image: http://iplimage.com/blog/approach-encodedecode-black-white-marker/]

I want to build a vb.net program that finds as many of this in a image. I do not need to get angels and so. Only a number.
The marker need to handler +10K of numbers and tolerate rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I did use https://github.com/jcmellado/js-aruco as a template to solve my problem.